# On exchange server when creating new users is there an easy way to copy mailbox rights between accounts?

Tags: active-directory, permissions, exchange

We currently have an exchange server setup at work and need to add a large number of users which will all share the same mailbox rights. We currently have around 17 permissions which must be added to each new user and we need a way to simplify the process or copy rights between two users. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to create a template user account and set the permissions on this user account. When you create new "real" user accounts simply copy the template user.

Comment: Well if what your saying is to essentially create the user via the copy function, this is basically what I have been doing but the mailbox rights have not been copying in this process.